# (WPF Datagrid) What if the user tried to edit a row but didn't actually changed the value

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

What if the user selected one cell and changed the value, but changed his mind not to change(leave the cell with original value)?
In this case, I want rowState of that row not to be changed to "MODIFIED" but it actually turns to "MODIFIED" from "UNCHANGED".

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you detecting the row changes, e.g. which event are you listening for?

Answer (score 0):

There are some possible mistakes:
1. Check, if you correctly set binding of your datagrid/datagrid column
2. Check, if binded collection implement INotifyPropertyChanged
3. Check, if you didnt set another UpdateSourseTrigger
4. Check, if you set correct mode, if you dont change this collection in datagrid only